# (Negative すぎる 'too much') when to use なすぎる and なさすぎる

Tags: grammar, negation

I understand there are two forms meaning 'too little' or too few', I thought the regular way to conjugate the negative was ない-form verb, and the last い is replaced with さ, making なさすぎる. (e.g 食べなさすぎる) But at the end of the chapter it says you can also use なすぎる with 'most regular i-adjectives'such as 危なすぎる 'not too dangerous'. Please can someone explain this to me.

Comment: Are you sure you read this correctly? 危ない means 'dangerous'. It's not a negation. So 危なすぎる would mean 'too dangerous' wouldn't it?

Comment: Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search) before asking your question?